# Jquery autocomplete crashes when trying to update other textbox (asp.net core project)

Tags: javascript, jquery, autocomplete

I have already had great [help](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36530780/jquery-autocomplete-not-working) of this piece of code. I am trying to now update another textbox when a jquery autocomplete option is picked.

I made a couple of changes specifically to display two of the options in the multi dimensional array:

```
a = $.map(a, function (x) {
                    return {
                        label: x.suburb + " - " + x.postCode,
                        value: x.suburb,
                        suburbDetails: x
                    };
```

The second change however breaks it and I cannot workout what form this line of code needs to be to pick and place the postcode in the #postcode textbox.

I have a [Jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/q8oLc6ec/8/) where it works (as an aside css doesnt work either here or in the project select eg "b") when the line is commented out but crashes when its uncommented.

```
$("#Postcode").val(data.suburbDetails.postCode)
```

How would you update the postcode textbox with the associated postcode for the suburb given both are/should be accessable via "data.suburbDetails"?

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/q8oLc6ec/9/

Comment: Yep that worked - spent ages on that one.. thankyou.

Comment: happy to help you..;)